# How can I add a int variable to a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, text

I need to add rand_Num to a blank txt file called Rand_Number. I need to do this 100000 times. Here's my code...
    # imports required libraries

```
import random
import turtle

# screen variables

wn_wid = 550
wn_length = 350
wn_title = "Random output"
wn_background_col = "#3d3d3d"
wn_tracer = 0

# creates and configures window

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(wn_wid, wn_length)
wn.title(wn_title)
wn.bgcolor(wn_background_col)
wn.tracer(wn_tracer)

# creates text

text = turtle.Turtle()
text.speed(0)
text.color("#ffffff")
text.pu()
text.hideturtle()

# text variables

font = "Comic Sans MS"
font_size = 48
alignment = "center"

# rep_num variable

rep_Num = 0

# central loop

# loop repeat variable

repeats = 100000

 # main loop

 for reps in range(repeats):

     # adds 1 to rep_Num variable

    rep_Num += 1

    # generates random number

    rand_Num = random.randint(0, 100)

    # puts text on screen

    text.clear()
    text.write(str(rep_Num) + ": " + str(rand_Num), align=alignment, font=(font, font_size, "normal"))

    # checks to see whether it needs to close win

    if rep_Num == repeats:
        wn.bye()
        break

    # updates window

    wn.update()
```

That is all my code and that all works as I want. I just need to have some thing in the loop that lets me add the rand_Num variable to a new line in a txt called Rand_Numbers

Comment: There are many tutorials on how to write to a file from Python. SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python file write tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with the CSV module, which will make it easy to add additional data as your project grows. Even if that is not your intent, the resulting file can still be easily used for data analysis purposes. A text file can also be generated this way if it is truly what you need.

I added this function:

```
def write_random(rand_Num):
    num = [rand_Num]
    with open("random_values.csv", "a", newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(num)
```

It generates a csv file (which can be processed by Excel just in case you want to do data analysis with your data or something) with each random value on a seperate line.

If you really want a text file, you can just change the extension from .csv to .txt so long as you are only including one piece of data per line.

Here is the full working code:

```
import random
import turtle
import csv
def write_random(rand_Num):
    num = [rand_Num]
    with open("Rand_Number.csv", "a", newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(num)
# screen variables
wn_wid = 550
wn_length = 350
wn_title = "Random output"
wn_background_col = "#3d3d3d"
wn_tracer = 0

# creates and configures window
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(wn_wid, wn_length)
wn.title(wn_title)
wn.bgcolor(wn_background_col)
wn.tracer(wn_tracer)

# creates text

text = turtle.Turtle()
text.speed(0)
text.color("#ffffff")
text.pu()
text.hideturtle()

# text variables

font = "Comic Sans MS"
font_size = 48
alignment = "center"

# rep_num variable

rep_Num = 0

# central loop

# loop repeat variable

repeats = 100000

# main loop

for reps in range(repeats):

    # adds 1 to rep_Num variable

    rep_Num += 1

    # generates random number

    rand_Num = random.randint(0, 100)
    write_random(rand_Num)
    # puts text on screen

    text.clear()
    text.write(str(rep_Num) + ": " + str(rand_Num), align=alignment, font=(font, font_size, "normal"))

    # checks to see whether it needs to close win

    if rep_Num == repeats:
        wn.bye()
        break

    # updates window

    wn.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with open(file)` synthax. I would write something like this :

```
with open('Rand_Numbers', 'w') as f:
    for reps in range(repeats):

        # adds 1 to rep_Num variable

        rep_Num += 1

        # generates random number

        rand_Num = random.randint(0, 100)
        f.write(str(rand_Num))

        # puts text on screen

        text.clear()
        text.write(str(rep_Num) + ": " + str(rand_Num), align=alignment, font=(font, font_size, "normal"))

        # checks to see whether it needs to close win

        if rep_Num == repeats:
            wn.bye()
            break

        # updates window

        wn.update()
```

By the way, you should remove `rep_Num = 0` and

```
if rep_Num == repeats:
       wn.bye()
       break
```

in your code since your loop does already the job.
`wn.bye()` would be added after the loop.